# How to delete WhatsApp Cloud API recipient phone numbers

Tags: cloud, whatsapp

I have added the 5 maximum recipient phone numbers, but now I cannot delete them, ... how do I delete and replace them? ... when I click the "Manage phone number list" button it only offers the ability to ADD phone numbers but no DELETE button is available in order to remove any of the 5 added numbers.

[image: WhatsApp cloud api getting started screen]

[image: Manage phone number list]

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible, when you click on "Manage phone number list" it gives you the option to delete an added phone.

If you are trying to delete the recipient phone number from the WhatsApp Business Account, you cannot do it from there. It can be deleted only from the App -> WhatsApp integration -> Setup

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Once this number has been added, it cannot be removed from your list, read the second point in this documentation,
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/get-started#sent-test-message

I would suggest you create a new developer app and add new numbers.